# Download of just Android AAPT for Debian 5.0

Tags: android, debian, aapt

I need Android AAPT that comes with the *platform-tools*. Since I do not want to install the entire SDK I'd be glad if someone could provide a download for just AAPT for Debian Linux 5.0.
AAPT is required to read a versionName and versionCode from several APK files which are stored on the server. To provide the latest version to a client I need to check the AndroidManifest.xml

Thanks in advance for your help,
steff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, fired up an Ubuntu live and took care of it myself. If anyone else needs aapt for linux feel free to download it from [here](http://pocketbee.uni-konstanz.de/cc/downloads/aapt)